# Will solo matchmaking match you solo players from the main queue?

Tags: dota-2

In Dota 2, solo matchmaking will look up only players who aren't in a party. Will it match this condition only with other players in the solo matchmaking queue, or will it get people from the common queue too?

I'm just afraid that this queue mode is not using the common queue. If not, I'll send a suggestion to the dev team.

Comment: Only solo queue. Otherwise there wouldn't be a point...

Comment: @Decency Why not? Solo matchmaking would be really faster if it look up in the common queue too..

Comment: If you can solo queue and match with parties, there's no reason to have a separate solo queue, since you can just join the regular queue by yourself. There's a tradeoff in matchmaking between speed of search and quality of game. I think you should try to reword your question.

Comment: @Decency may you don't get it..  Solo matchmaking would be really faster if it look up in the common queue too for **players that aren't in party but are in the common queue anyway**

Comment: I don't know if this is answerable by anyone who's not from valve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played solo a few days ago, and I can definitely say that I had a four friends premade team on the opponents side. I chatted with them, and they said so too.

So, that's evidence that the solo matchmaking gets players out of the common queue too.
(Maybe there is first a checkup, and only if there are not enough people in the solo queue the common queue will be added to your pool, but you can definitely say that there is the possibility to get common queue members in solo matchmaking!!!)

Comment: Agreed. It seems to take **very** much longer to find a match in this queue for others reasons like the common queue being used only at a certain search range and, obviously, for a bunch of in-party-players excluded from the main queue.

Comment: So, if there was a premade team in the solo queue, then the solo queue is just a blatant lie? The whole point of it is to not encounter premades.

Comment: @Ullallulloo:

I wouldn't say it is a whole lie, but they have to balance it if there are not enough ppl within the solo matchmaking to start games reliable and steady. (Could be one of much reasons I think!)

Comment: @Knorke: [I don't see any other claims of that though.](http://www.google.com/search?q=solo+queue+only+premade+dota+2+matchmaking&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A5%2F9%2F2013) [PCGamesN says, "The new queue will only be populated by solo players; cutting out the chance of going head to head against pre made teams."](http://www.pcgamesn.com/dota/dota-2-update-adds-solo-matchmaking-and-all-custom-uis), and up until recently, there were a lot of complaints about really long wait times in the solo queue, so that wouldn't have even been doing much good. Are you sure they couldn't have just been making a joke?

Comment: @Ullallulloo: I only know, that I played in solo matchmaking against ppl with the same clan tag and they confirmed that they are friends.

A friend of mine (whose playing dota since 13 years) told me that the new matchmaking only proofs the team points (lvl's) and adjust them until both teams match.

So if there are for example 230 lvl points in your team, the opponents team will have the same amount, but you don't know how much lvl's any player has.There is the possibility to get 1 player on lvl 226 and 4 players on lvl 1.

Comment: @Ullallullo: Often it's better mixed than that....but the possibility is existing.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that Normal queue and Solo queue do not share the same player pool. If you queue in Solo queue you are going to be matched only with people that queued in the Solo queue aswell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it was before making solo an option, but at least now it definitely includes the people queueing for both. I tried asking around in games to see if anyone didn't pick "solo only", and I found very few people who actually had.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have exact proof, but based on statistics it's very probable that it uses the common queue.

I come to this conclusion because I've played against a few teams made up primarily of people with the same tag before their name.  Coincidences or people changing their names during the game? maybe, but highly unlikely for every time I've seen it.

I'll try to look through some of my games to see if I can screenshot a few for reference later

Comment: Why would people with the same tag be more likely to come from the common queue if they're soloing?

Comment: what? if they have the same tag, as in they're with friends, then it means they joined together. thus not soloing

Comment: So then you're saying that it not only matches you with solo players from the common pool, but also with non-solo players from the common pool? Isn't it not doing that the entire point of having a solo queue?